# Java process always return -1

Tags: java, c

I am trying to use C library(CFM-ID) from my java program. There are executable files in bin folder of C project.
When I run C project from terminal, its working.

```
cd /home/lclab/cfm-svn/cfm/bin
./fraggraph-gen CC 2 + fullgraph
```

fraggraph-gen is the executable file. Then I tried it with my java program

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String command = "/home/lclab/cfm-svn/cfm/bin/fraggraph-gen CC 2 + fullgraph";
Process pr= rt.exec(command);
InputStream in = pr.getInputStream();
System.out.println(in.read());
```

But it always return -1.
then I've created C program and implemented executable file.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  {

   if( argc == 2 ) {
      printf("The argument supplied is %s\n", argv[1]);
   }
   else if( argc > 2 ) {
      printf("Too many arguments supplied.\n");
   }
   else {
      printf("One argument expected.\n");
   }
}
```

And executed it by my Java program by changing the command variable.

```
String command = "/home/lclab/Desktop/jni/test param1";
```

Its working. Please be kind to give me a solution for this issue. Thanks

Comment: Notice that when you're running your program from the terminal you enter the program's directory before launching it. When you run it from your Java program you're not. What does your program do? Does it expect to be run in its own directory? (maybe because it accesses files in there). It's hard to help you without knowing what your C program does.

Comment: From the Javadoc for `Process`: "As of 1.5, `ProcessBuilder.start()` is the preferred way to create a Process." -- this won't solve this specific problem, but it will make working with processes easier in general.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I executed both C programs in same order(with terminal and java).Both programs workig with terminal , But only test program is working with java. library is not. How to run C program by java, which C program is using other classes in C project?

Answer (score 0):

Following debugging steps might help you:

1. Check arguments that you supplied in your dumy executable. Print them and compare with expected results.
2. Don't you need to use waitFor: `pr.waitFor()`
3. You may want to print error stream for the child process: `pr.getErrorStream()`
4. From Terminal, you first change directory using `cd` command, but not when executing from Java. Consider setting process directory before executing process, something like [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have done same execution order for my testing C program and C library. First I tried with terminal and then with java. But its working only for testing program. Testing program is independent program and library is using another classes I think. It is the different. If you can please give some suggestion.Thanks

Comment: @user3558507, Ideally there should be no difference in executing a program from terminal or `Runtime().exec()`. I could think of only two reasons: A. `pwd` is different because of a missing `cd` command. But this is already checked by you. B. Check whether arguments are supplied correctly, notice there is a sigil `+` in arguments. 
Also, if you can give the exact error, it would be helpful.